# UnsupportedClassVersionError with GWT 2.6 and jdk 1.6

Tags: java, gwt, java-6, gwt-super-dev-mode

I get this error if I try to debug in super dev mode:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/google/appengine/tools/development/agent/AppEngineDevAgent : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:280)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:338)
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
Exception in thread "main"
```

my Eclipse(Mars) runs currently with jdk `1.6_23` because that's currently my Java version thats running on my tomcat.
The Compiler is set to 1.6 and the project facets too.

Compile the project with GWT Compile runs fine...

I am working for hours on that problem and I dont see the problem...

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppEngine requires Java 7. If you're not doing AppEngine-related work, disable it in Eclipse; otherwise update to Java 7.